# TypeScript: 'handleFirstTab' was used before it was defined @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

I have the following code in a React Component and TypeScript gives the following error:

`'handleFirstTab' was used before it was defined  @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define`

If I split both functions into separate files and import them in each other then the error goes away. Is there a way via which I can have both functions in the same file without disabling `@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define` and the error will go away. Thanks.

```
  const handleMouseDownOnce = (): void => {
    document.body.classList.remove('user-is-tabbing')
    window.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDownOnce)
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab)
  }

  const handleFirstTab = (e: KeyboardEvent): void => {
    if (e.code === 'Tab') {
      document.body.classList.add('user-is-tabbing')
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab)
      window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDownOnce)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unless you want to add an ESLint disable comment for this specific instance, any way in which you define these functions within the same file will be breaking that ESLint rule, since no matter which you declare first, it will always reference the undefined second function.
I don't know your full implementation but instead it might be worth thinking of a way to refactor these two methods so they aren't referencing each other.

Comment: Have you tried to use a function declaration (`function handleMouseDownOnce() { ... }`) instead of function expression (`const handleMouseDownOnce = () => { ... }`)?

Comment: Thanks, @Shlang I have tried function declaration but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

when you define a variable (or function) using `const` or `let` it won't be `Hoist` as function declaration using `function` keyword or using `var`

if you want to have both of them in the same file you need to change your code like following:

```
  function handleMouseDownOnce(): void {
    document.body.classList.remove('user-is-tabbing')
    window.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDownOnce)
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab)
  }

  function handleFirstTab(e: KeyboardEvent): void{
    if (e.code === 'Tab') {
      document.body.classList.add('user-is-tabbing')
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab)
      window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDownOnce)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @taghi-khavari It does not work. I'm still having the same error.

Comment: so there is no way , you have to either disable the @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define or use ```@ts-ignore``` in your file
because you're explicitly saying to make an error when that happened

Comment: @SyedNisarHassan You might want to change to config for this rule to avoid an error in this particullar situation `"@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error", { "functions": false }]`. It is safe since function declarations are hoisted.